# Hyperlink in data table is not in blue color

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

I am creating eFile Number field as a hyperlink in lightning data table but it is not in blue color

```
           for(let key in data) 
       {
           console.log('data -'+data );
           console.log('value -'+data[key]);     
           if(key==='eFile Number')
           {
               this.columns.push({label: 'eFile Number', fieldName: 'DisplayeFile__c', type: 
           'url',typeAttributes: {label: { fieldName: 'CaseNumber'},target: '_self'},sortable : 'true'});
             }
```

Note - DisplayeFile__c is a formula field which is returning a eFile Number url

eFile Number became hyperlink but it is not in a blue color
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To display a link, you need to mark the type of the column as a url and also provide a field to display which I see you are already doing.

If it is becoming a link but not showing correct colour, it is likely that there is some CSS overriding yours or if you are using it in the community, the link colour might be black.

Comment: I had applied the css but it is not  working when i inspected the component in browser i had not found the css which i had applied.